# Call function from controller from within event function of a responsivepopup

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a responsivepopup containing a list in mode 'Delete'.
When I click to delete an item a function is called on press.
Withing this function 'this' is the oList and oEvent.oSource is also the oList.
From within the event function I need to call a function in my controller.
I can't find a way to reference my controller, not even using sap..core..byId("Detail") or even the full namespace.
I tried walking up the elemnt tree from oEvent.oSource.getParent().getParent() to then call .getController() but it's a dead end.

```
        handlePressViewSelection: function(oEvent) {
        var oResourceBundle = this.getResourceBundle();

        //create the list
        var oList = new sap.m.List({
            mode: "Delete",
            delete: this.handleDeleteSelectionItem
        });

        oList.setModel(this._oSelectedTrainingsModel);

        var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
            title : "{Title}",
            description : "{=${Begda} ? ${Type} - { path: 'Begda', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style: 'medium' }} : ${Type}}",
            icon : "{icon}",
            iconInset : false
        });

        oList.bindAggregation("items", {
            path: "/",
            template: oItemTemplate,
            type: "Active"
        });

        var oBeginButton = new sap.m.Button({
            text: "Action1",
            type: sap.m.ButtonType.Reject,
            press: function(){
                oResponsivePopover.setShowCloseButton(false);
            }
        });
        var oEndButton = new sap.m.Button({
            text: "Action2",
            type: sap.m.ButtonType.Accept,
            press: function(){
                oResponsivePopover.setShowCloseButton(true);
            }
        });

        var oResponsivePopover = new sap.m.ResponsivePopover({
            placement: sap.m.PlacementType.Bottom,
            title: "",
            showHeader: false,
            beginButton: oBeginButton,
            endButton: oEndButton,
            horizontalScrolling: false,
            content: [
                oList
            ]
        });

        oResponsivePopover.openBy(oEvent.oSource);
    },

        handleDeleteSelectionItem: function(oEvent) {
        var oListItem = oEvent.getParameter('listItem');
        var oList = oListItem.getParent();
        var path = oListItem.getBindingContext().sPath;
        oList.getModel().getData().splice(parseInt(path.substring(1)), 1);
        oList.removeItem(oEvent.getParameter('listItem'));
        oList.getParent().getParent().getController()._updateViewSelectionButtonText(); //--> BROKEN
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate your popup from a fragment, you can specify "a Controller to be used for event handlers in the Fragment" (see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.xmlfragment)

For example:

```js
onOpenResponsivePopover : function(oEvent) {

    if (!this._oResponsivePopover) {
        // adding 'this' makes sure you specify the current controller to be used for event handlers 
        this._oResponsivePopover = sap.ui.xmlfragment("namespace.to.your.popoverfragment", this); 
        this.getView().addDependent(this._oResponsivePopover);
    }

    this._oResponsivePopover.openBy(oEvent.getSource());
},
```

Comment: And when you're not using a fragment, but create the popover purely in JS?

Comment: Can you update your question with code how you instantiate your popover control?

Comment: Pieter, I assume you are creating the popover inside the controller? If yes, you can use bind(this), I believe. Probably you should quote your code in the original post.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're creating the popup UI inside the controller? To me it seems `this.handleDeleteSelectionItem` should work just fine (providing method `handleDeleteSelectionItem` exists in the same controller) - However, for easier coding and maintenance, I would advise to put the popup UI in a separate JSFragment

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear, this.handleDeleteSelectionItem does work. It is in that function however that I'm not able to call another function from my controller...

Comment: OK Done, see original post.

Comment: Can you try with `delete: [this.handleDeleteSelectionItem, this]` in your List delete definition?

Comment: That works! I've never known you could do this. How should I've known? Is it also possible this way to pass parameters like [this.handleDeleteSelectionItem, this, param1, param2]?

Comment: It isn't that clear from the API, but if you look at the Constructor Detail part of ListBase (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#constructor), under 'events' it mentioned: `delete : fnListenerFunction or [fnListenerFunction, oListenerObject] or [oData, fnListenerFunction, oListenerObject]`. So to answer your 2nd question, you could pass an object as the first argument.